# Implement 3rd party Web Service API as 'Pages' in Wordpress

Tags: php, json, wordpress, curl

I'm using building out a section of a Wordpress site that uses an API built on top of an older database that needs to remain in tact. The API is really simple and will be accessed only in two ways:

```
mysite.com/monkeys/     <-- This corresponds to calling the API as '/api/monkeys/list'
mysite.com/monkey/william    <-- Calling the API as '/api/monkeys/:name'
```

Because the data from the API is controlled by a 3rd party and does not need to be managed by Wordpress, I'm wondering how best I can build this out so that Wordpress doesn't throw 404s/redirect when I try to hit these urls.

Furthermore, if I decide to cache these calls (the API is clunky and slow) how might I integrate them into a Wordpress search?

Please let me know if I can clarify anything - thanks!

Comment: Can't you create a custom Wordpress template, use PHP to get and trim the URL, then use this data to make calls to the external API?

Comment: I'm doing that currently as a temporary solution, but I guess I'm more so wondering how I could integrate that with Wordpress search. Any ideas?

Comment: To my understanding the WordPress search works by searching the title and content of each post/page. I think the easiest way would be to update the post content every time you run the PHP code to grab data from the API. This means, aside from displaying the data from the API, you would also save it to the `post_content` field of the `wp_posts` table. Obviously, you would also have to identify which row in the table corresponds to the current page, but that shouldn't be very difficult to do.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like a step in the right direction. I'll poke around the Codex a bit more with this in mind.

Comment: Glad I could be of some assistance, good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an [endpoint](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint). The following example only detects endpoints on the root ([`EP_ROOT`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint#Available_Places)). If we visit `example.com/monkeys/` it's considered your `/api/monkeys/list`. And when visiting `example.com/monkeys/name` it's your `/api/monkeys/:name`.

If you really want to separate a monkey from the band, add another endpoint.

```
add_action( 'init', function()
{
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'monkeys', EP_ROOT );
});

add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $vars )
{
    $vars[] = 'monkeys';
    return $vars;
});
```

This code requires refreshing the permalinks manually in `Settings >> Permalinks >> Save`, but it can be [auto refreshed on plugin activation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24331768/1287812).

To test the endpoint, I used this:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function(){
    // set default as 'empty', so we can differentiate the root from no query var
    $monkeys = get_query_var( 'monkeys','empty' ); 
    if( 'empty' === $monkeys ) {
        printf( '<h1 style="font-size:4em">%s</h1>', 'NOT SET' );
    }
    else if( '' === $monkeys ) {
        printf( '<h1 style="font-size:4em">%s</h1>', 'Endpoint root.' );
    } 
    else {
        printf( '<h1 style="font-size:4em">Sent query: %s</h1>', urldecode( $monkeys ) );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create those resources ... they won't be 404 *then* ...

We've used this approach successfully on OMBE; we simply created scripts (in your case they'd be "monkey" and "monkeys") which are wrappers for something else (like the API in your case) and used an Apache ForceType directive (pointing to application/x-httpd-php5) to handle them.

HTH,